# React.js - input in component is not detected by form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got two components: FormSection and InputWrapper. If input wrapped in div is rendered by FormSection method, there is absolutely no problem with sending form data to server. But if I render wrapped input with use of InputWrapper component, the only thing that server gets is CSRF token.

Client-side form validation works properly (e.g. if input is set to required and value of it is blank, browser shows an error). Is there way to make it with separate component for input?

FormSection

```
class FormSection extends React.Component {
   constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);

      this.state = {
          inputs: [
              {id: 'id_title', name: 'title' key:'title', label: "Title"},
              {id: 'id_director', name: 'director' key:'director', label: "Director"}
          ]
       }
   }

   get_csrf_token() {
      ...
   }

   render() {
      return (<form action="/createmovie/" method="POST">
                  <input type='hidden' name='csrf' value={this.get_csrf_token()} />
                  {this.state.inputs.map(props => <InputWrapper {...props}) />)}
              </form>)
   }
}
```

InputWrapper

```
 class InputWrapper extends React.Component {
     handleFocus(event) {
      ...
     }
     render() {
         return (<div class="wrapped">
                   <label for={this.props.id}>{this.props.label}</label>
                   <input id={this.props.id} name={this.props.name} onFocus={this.handleFocus} />
                 </div>);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Seems to work after fixing some syntax errors: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/55477/

Comment: Could you provide a working demonstration of the problem? Because wrapping inputs in a component is not the cause, but there's no way to investigate further.